# Best practices for exporting images from vector / eps artwork

Tags: adobe-photoshop, vector, logo, file-format, eps

I'm taking my first steps into the waters of vector design, designing a simple logo (in 'Sketch' for mac - an illustrator alternative).

This went well until it came time to export the artwork for a web site. I took an eps to Fireworks, then created a PNG for the web site.

It wound up looking more 'jaggy' than I expected, and this is when I started to wonder whether I was doing things right.

What size/resolution do you import an eps logo into Fireworks (or Photoshop) at? The same size you want to end-graphic to be, or do you import as a larger size and shrink it down in Photoshop so it looks better?

Comment: Actually i think that pretty much every 2d vector rendering app does things wrong (oh why oh why cant i get sinc with lancoz window filetring in PS). Adobe especially is bad at this as they filter the signal as if the color space were linear. So I actually do my own antialiasing when i need superior quality stuff. So I agree that this is indeed a problem. But on whole different level. If you bring it in larger you have more values to filter in when you bring the nonlinearess into play.

Answer (score 2):

As a web developer, I would say you should export the images at the size you expect them to be rendered.

This is for two reasons:

a) Filesize - a 2MB file scaled down in terms of resolution, still has to be downloaded at 2MB

b) Rendering - a 1000x250px image which is displayed in a 250x50px  tag, will be rendered by the browser at runtime. This is both slow, and likely worse quality than you'd achieve in a specific graphics application.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest setting a Photoshop file up with the final resolution (depending what you want to use it for) and then importing the logo into Photoshop as **vector shapes** (from Illustator this works with copy/paste, not sure about "Sketch"). That way they stay lossless, even if you change the resolution later.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to export an *.eps file from Sketch and simple open it in Photoshop without any resizing. After that take an option which is called *'Save for Web'* (Shift+Cmd+Alt+s or from main menu *'File->Save for Web*') and resize your image to get the dimensions you need. Listen to the **dougajmcdonald** and prepare the size you expect them to be rendered in a browser. Select a *'Bicubic Sharper'* option if you want to decrease the size. It helps you to keep the details. In other way they could be blured too much.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Sketch to create the artwork, you should probably use Sketch to output the final bitmap images. Sketch can output in a few different bitmap formats, including PNG.

That's probably the easiest and fastest way to do it.

Comment: This is what I did initially, but the output did not seem to be of very good quality / resolution. Should I make the 'art board' or 'slide' the same size I want the ultimate graphic, or make it bigger to get better clarity?